# Web.xml: why so poor flexibility for url-patterns in security contraints ?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish, security, url-pattern

I'm using GlassFish 3.1 and wanted to use container authentication. 
When I started writing security constraint in the web.xml I had the feeling that url patterns have very little flexibility.
Chapter 12.2 in the  Servlet specification 3.0 describes the valid url patterns for servlet mapping:

1. List item
2. /something/* for path mapping
3. *.extension for extension mapping
4. exact mapping
5. default and  context root cases

12.1 describes the matching algorithm
and at point 2 states:
The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done
by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as a
path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.

The security constraints are described in Chapter 13 and from 13.8.3 it seems that url-patterns and matching algorithm are the same of those for servlet.

Imagine you have a legacy application with JSF pages organized in the following way:
for each entity class there is a directory with the entity name which contains  4 JSF files (List, edit, create, view).
What if you want to protect access to edit and create pages ? It seems to me  you can only use 'exact match' in the url-pattern, so you have to write a constraint for each page you want to protect, very long and tedious, error prone activity.
Besides, if I protect and entire directory with a path mapping rule (such as **/customers/*** )  I cannot see any way to relief that constraint for a specific page inside that directory (for example if a want to free the access to page 'List' inside a protected directory).

During the experiments with Glassfish 3.1 I notices this weird behavior:
path mappings work well only if they are absolute from context root, so using jsf default configuration they must start with '**/faces**'. If I write **/customers/** instead of **/faces/customers/** the security constraint is not evaluated. According to me this is in contrast with what is stated at 12.1 (reported above).

Can somebody shed some light on how url-pattern can be effectively used for defining security constraints ?
Obviously you can put all sensitive JSF inside a '**/protected**' directory, but it is a very invasive way of achieving the goal with security that breaks any logical order of JSF.

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 0):

**Can somebody shed some light on how url-pattern can be effectively used for defining security constraints?**

I can't, after several years of Java EE I feel that Java EE security constraints are useful for authentication only. If it comes to authorization (is a known entity authorized to perform a certain action) this security model fails as it is too general (URL dependent). You could have a look at e.g. Spring Security. Depending on the complexity of the use case you may consider build-your-own - especially when it comes to data centric security (e.g. only users in organization A are allowed to modify data provided by organization B).

Not really an answer, but my opinion...

Comment: To complete my previous comment.Here [link](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html) I found some tutorials about web application security and all of them use the container authentication and authorization mechanism. I start to think these tutorials are a completely waste of time if you cannot adapt them to a real case. I hoped to find somebody who uses container authorization but it seems everybody relies on third party libraries for security...Am I wrong ??

Comment: @Filippo: I think it's worth having a look at the tutorials. Authorization is used today (and I used it as well), I just made the experience that at a certain point in time you come to a point where it's not enough any more... e.g. data level security. So you have to decide whether it makes sense to start with JEE authorization at all. Keep in mind that authentication is fine.